# if else loop on Python. Checking a class name with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, pycharm

I have this appointment system where i have to wait till the link is available. If this link its availble then click it. If not back and foward (beacause the page doesn't let me reload ). And check it again till is available.

```
while True:

    if driver.find_element_by_class_name("linkButton"):

            #do somthing



    else:

             driver.back()
             driver.forward()
             #check again.
```

The program doesn't throw any error but when i force the `if` to be `false` the `else` just do nothing.

I can't check it with the link that is not available because in the page is till available that's why i force the `if` to be `false`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `find_element_*()` methods don't return true/false, they either return a `WebElement` instance (which is truthy) or throw a `NoSuchElementException` exception (or other exception).

The existence check is usually done via `find_elements_*()` methods which, if an element is not found, would return an empty list, which is falsy:

```
while True:
    if driver.find_elements_by_class_name("linkButton"):
        # do something
    else:
        driver.refresh()
```

Note that I think you just meant to `refresh()` the page instead of going back and forward.

And, you should also add some time delays between the attempts.

Comment: Yes .. but i cant make selenium to find the element .. i tried with xpath `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_acc_Calendario1_myCalendario1']/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/input")`