# Calendar picker with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, testing, calendar, pycharm

I want to click a day of the calendar(doesn't matter what day) if it's available

There are days that are availables and other that they aren't.

The calendar is made with `table` tag, each `td` tag, if it isn't available ,  has a class `notSelectableDay`.

I have to reload the page till the program found a available day which has the class `selectableDay`.

The program structure its in this other question i made [if else loop on Python. Checking a class name with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164381/if-else-loop-on-python-checking-a-class-name-with-selenium/43164409#43164409)

Could this work:

```
if driver.find_elements_by_class_name("selectableDay"):

    driver.find_element_by_class_name("selectableDay").click()
```

I`ve made another question more clearly explainded :

[I got a calender picker. How to select the available day with Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422464/i-got-a-calender-picker-how-to-select-the-available-day-with-selenium-and-pytho?noredirect=1#comment73925168_43422464)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the piece of code where you can pick required date from the calendar. Just you need to pass date which you want to be selected from the calendar.

```
from selenium import webdriver 

def datepicker(date):
    driverInstance = webdriver.Chrome()
    driverInstance.get("http://www.seleniumframework.com/Practiceform/")
    driverInstance.maximize_window()
    driverInstance.find_element_by_id("vfb-8").click()
    elements = driverInstance.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr/td/a") 
    for dates in elements:
        if(dates.is_enabled() and dates.is_displayed() and str(dates.get_attribute("innerText")) == date):
            dates.click()
```

if you want to select date 10 from calendar the pass string "10" to the function

example: `datepicker("10")`

Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Thank you Krishna , but i want to chek a random number, i mean if there is a available day click it, i dont know what day is gonna be available..

Comment: If i do this `driver.find_element_by_class_name("calendarCellOpen").click()`  Is it gonna click the first (or any) day available ..?  Beacuse every available day has the `calendarCellOpen` class.

Comment: Besides can yo explain me a little bit the code. There are methods that i dont understand .

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_class_name("calendarCellOpen").click(‌​)` this line of code represents full parent node and it is not able to click any random date. So from the piece of code which i have written, I'm storing all the elements(dates) of the in calendar into list. If you want to pick random element from the list, use random function in python to pick any random element from the list to click.

Comment: Ok ..  but how do you exactly wrote the elements in dates.. ??

Comment: `.//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr/td/a` this xpath represent all the `a` links in calendar which is all the dates. Your xpath should represent all the date in calendar. I placed all those elements into list and verifying with text of each element with "required date" which we passed.

Comment: Ok. Thank s for the response but what are you exactly clicking her `driverInstance.find_element_by_id("vfb-8").click()` it doesn't make sense to me ... i made all the python code to reach the calendar url and then i have to click days  tag `td`

Comment: Actually i have taken some demo website to show you how to deal with date picker. There we need to click on text field so that date picker will be opened. `vfb-8` is locator of that text field.

Answer (score 0):

```
elementos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("calendarCellOpen")

   while True:

            if elementos:
                driver.find_element_by_class_name("calendarCellOpen").click()
                driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_acc_Calendario1_repFasce_ctl01_btnConferma").click() #Confirm button
            else:

                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='>']").click() #Forward the calendar
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='<']").click() #Back the calendar
                if elementos:
                    driver.find_element_by_class_name("calendarCellOpen").click()
                    driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_acc_Calendario1_repFasce_ctl01_btnConferma").click() #Confirm button
```

Maybe this can work .. instead find_element with xpath but i think it will work anyway..